# Private DynDns server with bind9

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, dyndns

I'm trying to build my own dynamic DNS server on my private online instance.

I started by installing the DNS server BIND9 on your Debian/Ubuntu server via:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install bind9.
```

added my zone in the /etc/bind/named.conf.local:

```
include "/etc/bind/ddns-keys.conf";
zone "d.example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.d.example.com";
        update-policy {
                grant *.d.example.com. self d.example.com. A AAAA TXT;
        };
        notify no;
};
```

I created my key with in /etc/bind/ddns-keys.conf:

```
dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-SHA512 -b 512 -n HOST sb.d.example.com.
```

added the db file for my zone /var/lib/bind/db.d.example.com:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 10 ; 10 seconds
d.example.com.             IN SOA  ns1.d.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                                2014080101      ; serial
                                120             ; refresh (2 minutes)
                                120             ; retry (2 minutes)
                                2419200         ; expire(4 weeks)
                                120             ; minimum (2 minutes)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.d.example.com.
                        NS      ns2.d.example.com.

$ORIGIN d.example.com.
$TTL 30 ; 30 seconds
ipv4                    A       38.68.84.19
ipv4v6                  A       38.68.84.19
                        AAAA    2001:0db8::2
ipv6                    AAAA    2001:0db8::2

ns1                     A       38.68.84.19
ns2                     AAAA    2001:0db8::2
```

I also checked and reloaded the conf:

```
named-checkconf
named-checkzone d.example.com /var/lib/bind/db.d.example.com
/etc/init.d/bind9 reload
```

But the subdomains are not resolved.

Any idea help is very appreciated.

Comment: Don't you forget to increment serial number?

Comment: I put a random number for the serial, how about main domain provider configuration?

Comment: now it's working because I missed to set the NS on the domain registar page. The only problem left is the subdomain TEST.example.com which is not working, any idea?